Pgadmin не открывается
скачал постгрес, но pgadmin вечно не запускается, пишет такую ошибку:
The pgAdmin 4 server could not be contacted:Total spawn time to start the pgAdmin4 server: 0.007 Sec
2024-04-14 15:14:37,560: WARNING    werkzeug:   Werkzeug appears to be used in a production deployment. Consider switching to a production web server instead.

Serving Flask app 'pgadmin'
Debug mode: off

что делать?
